# Session / authentication data not persisting in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5.3

I'm attempting to migrate a project from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 5.3, by migrating the functionality of the old codebase into a brand new Laravel 5.3 installation. My project uses Socialite to enable Google OAuth authentication, which isn't working.

I've tried to isolate the problem by writing two test routes in the web routes file, `web.php`.

The first test route manually attempts a login of an `AdminUser` instance, and also puts a value in the session. The instance is being fetched from the database correctly.

```
Route::get('/test/signin', function(Request $request) {

    $user = \App\AdminUser::find(1);
    Auth::guard('web')->login($user);

    // Set a test value in the session
    session(['test_key' => 'test_value');

    // Print all data in the session
    print_r($request->session()->all());

    // Returns true
    return var_dump(Auth::check());
});
```

Hitting this route returns `true`, signifying that the authentication worked. The session data that is printed includes the `['test_key' => 'test_value']` that is set.

The second route checks authentication and prints out all the data in the session, once again.

```
Route::get('/test/checkauth', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    // Print all data in the session
    print_r($request->session()->all());

    // Try to get the current authenticated user instance (prints null)
    echo var_dump(Auth::guard('web')->user());

    // Try to get the authenticated user instance in a different way (also prints null)
    echo var_dump($request->user());

    // Returns false
    return var_dump(Auth::guard('web')->check());
});
```

When visiting this route immediately after visiting the `/test/signin` route, it does **not** show the `['test_key' => 'test_value']` pair that was set in the first route, it prints `null` when trying to fetch the authenticated user instance, and it returns `false` when checking auth status via `Auth::check()`.

The session driver is set to `file` in `.env`, and I have checked the directory permissions of the `storage/framework/sessions` folder.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Are your routes inside `web` middleware?

Comment: @RossWilson They're in the ``routes/web.php`` file;  ``web`` middleware is automatically applied to all routes in that file.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `app/Http/Kernel.php`?

Comment: @RossWilson ``Kernel.php`` is unmodified from the default, as it is here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.3.16/app/Http/Kernel.php. It includes the ``StartSession`` and ``ShareErrorsFromSession`` classes in the ``web`` middleware group.